# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to1^+}\ln x\ln(\ln x)$ without L'hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to evaluate the following limit :$$L=\lim_{x\to1^+}\ln x\ln(\ln x)$$

**My efforts:**

$$L =\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$$

By L'hospital rule, clearly :

$$L = \lim_{x\to1^+}(-\ln x)=0$$

But I am looking into any other way to evaluate it. Thanks !

Comment: The domain of $\ln(x)$ is $x\in (0,\infty )$, thus you cannot approach $x\to 1^-$ since that would make $\ln(x)<0$ then $\ln(\ln(x))$ would be undefined.

Comment: Yes I get it. I'll edit it to make one-sided limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=e^t$, then the limit is:
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} t \log t=0 $$
which can be proven without L'Hopital's rule as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258273/1118406).

Comment: Please show without L'Hospital rule that how $\lim_{t\to 0} t \log t=0$. Thanks !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631205/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-lim-x-to-0-lnxx-0-without-lhospitals-r

Comment: @An_Elephant take a [look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258273/1118406)

Comment: @SineoftheTime Okay thanks. Please add that link then to answer than in comments.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0}t\log t$ is not well defined, $\lim_{t\to0^-}t\log t$ does not make sense

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez Yes you're right. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I had the first mistake in my answer :)

Comment: @SineoftheTime Hi, I know I shouldn't ask this in comments but I'm afraid if it's okay to ask such a question as another post. Can gamma function have more than one argument ? I have thought it's a single valued function but wolfram is giving answers to my questions in the form of multivalued gamma function. Please tell is it a standard notation or not . Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant Are you referring to the [Incomplete Gamma Function ?](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html)

Comment: @SineoftheTime Ooh thanks very much for link.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 1}\ln x\ln(\ln x)=\lim_{x\to 1}\ln\left((\ln x)^{\ln x}\right)=\ln \lim_{x\to 1}\left((\ln x)^{\ln x}\right).$$ So we have to compute $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left((\ln x)^{\ln x}\right).$$ Take $t=\ln x$, so the limit converts to $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^t,$$ whose limit is $1$, this have been answered here many times. So $$L=\ln 1=0.$$ The fact that $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^t,$$ is basically that $x\ln x\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$. To show this without using L'hopital check this [$\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x \ln x$ without l'Hopital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522973/lim-x-to0-x-ln-x-without-lhopitals-rule)

Comment: Thanks. But the linked question is concerned with $x\to 0^+$ not $x\to 0$.

Comment: The chane $t=\ln x$ converts $x\to 1$ to $t\to 0^+$, because $\ln x$ is defined to $x>0$, so there's no issue here

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

By another way, let $x=e^{e^y}\to 1^+$ with $y\to -\infty$ then

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\ln x\ln(\ln x)=\lim_{y\to-\infty }te^t=$$

which is a well known standard limit (exponential vs power) which goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. The last limit is much more obvious.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

When $x\to 1$ we have $l = \ln(x)\sim x-1$, so:
$$l=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\ln(x)\cdot\ln(\ln(x))\sim \lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1)\cdot\ln(x-1)$$

Let $t=x-1$, thus:
$$l=\lim_{t\to 0^+} t\cdot\ln(t)=\lim_{s\to +\infty}-\frac{\ln(s)}{s}=0$$ for $s=1/t$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew of first approximation.